# @IsOptional() validator doesn't ignore class IsUrl and IsDate

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to work with class validator in Nestjs, somehow when I implement `@IsOptional()` class validator in create-assignment.dto.ts, IsOptional doesn't ignore  `@IsDate()` and `@IsUrl()` in picture and deadline

```
import {
  IsDate,
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsOptional,
  IsString,
  IsUrl,
} from 'class-validator';

export class CreateAssignmentDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  title: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsUrl()
  picture?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  description?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsDate()
  deadline?: string;
}
```

[image: this is what the response look like here]

I tried to drop `@isUrl` and `@Isdate` and replace them with `@IsString` and it worked normally.

Comment: Have you tried passing `skipMissingProperties` to `validate` function as option? It seems that setting that property will allow any missing properties to be ignore (achieving what you are looking for). If any property is always required, use `IsDefined()`.

Comment: setting skipMissingProperties does not work for me in app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({})

Comment: I still stucking with this problem I have also tried to add skipMissingProperties still not working any update on this issue?